# How to add edit links on woocommerce pages?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to add edit links to my woocommerce pages as well as all products on archive page.

For the page itself, I tried this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woo_page_edit_link', 10 );

function woo_page_edit_link() {
    edit_post_link( 'e', '', '' );
}
```

But instead of the page id, I always get the id of the first product listed.

For the loop, I tried this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' , 'woo_item_edit_link');

function woo_item_edit_link() {
    edit_post_link( 'e', '', '' );
}
```

But the edit link always gets nested *inside* the shop item link.

Any ideas how to resolve both problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`woocommerce_before_shop_loop` is before the loop markup, but the product query is already set up, so the current `$post` is for the first product. You can use the 4th parameter of `edit_post_link()` to define a specific page ID. WooCommerce has a built-in function for getting the page IDs of it's custom pages.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woo_page_edit_link', 10 );

function woo_page_edit_link() {
    edit_post_link( 'edit shop', '', '', wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) );
}
```

And your item edit link appears inside the link because `woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open()` is hooked to `woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item` with a priority of 10. So if you add your function on the same (or later) priority, you risk being inside the link. To counter this, you can use an earlier priority like below.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' , 'woo_item_edit_link', 5);

function woo_item_edit_link() {
    edit_post_link( 'edit product' );
}
```